# Magento, Full Page Cache , Memcache and Redis

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache, redis, memcached

I recently installed Full Page Cache by Mirasvit, but I had a couple of issues:

1. Pages became really static, home page and electronic chart were always the same, same username for everybody, same products. Same happened on the back office. I had to disable it.
2. Load on the server and CPU consumption is exactly the same, speed is the same

I tried to install Memcache, but I had problem with pages not refreshable, I had to force refresh to see the real page, not the last, even in the backend.

I would like to try Redis.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> Pages became really static

That's the purpose of a cache.

> Load on the server and CPU consumption is exactly the same

That's because you tried a quick fix of installing a cache rather than addressing the actual issue. Fix whatever is actually the performance bottleneck on your store.

Ie. Profile your code, review the server and application stats and make an intelligent decision as to what the bottleneck is.

Whether you use file storage, memcached or Redis for your cache store, I doubt any will solve your issue - because the speed of the cache storage is unlikely to be the reason for your high CPU usage.

I would suggest setting up proper graphing and logging on your server, identify the real reason for high CPU and fix that.

Don't ever install a cache to fix a performance/capacity issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Lesti FPC (https://gordonlesti.com/lestifpc/). It is a really good cache extension and works with both Memcache en Redis. In the settings in Magento backend, you can easily adjust which pages or page types should be cached and which not. This prevents the issues you mention (i.e. the same user name for each visitor).

Answer (score 0):

Mirasvit full page cache is an excellent extension, and from my personal experience one of the best companies of magento extensions.  So first and foremost you need to contact their support.

Additionally get a general idea of how the different caches work.  The caches you have mentioned are not interchangeable, and have very different functions.

Full page cache is meant to make your pages static, but Mirasvit has many default hole punches in place for common dynamic content.  There are many settings in the admin as well with Mirasvit FPC where you can set certain pages to not cache, as well you can set dynamic content on a per page basis.

Do a lot of reading on full page cache systems and hole punching.